# Getting width of html img element with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the value of an img tag with HtmlAgility pack like...

```
          HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute width = link.Attributes["width"];
          HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute height = link.Attributes["height"];
```

but this returns 50px. however, I need only 50 to convert to number. Any helpppp please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't an `int.Parse(value.Replace("px", string.Empty))` fine for you? If there's a `px` suffix it will disappear before parsing and if there isn't, it's cool, we could parse directly to an integer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, pretty trivially, by chaining the `.Replace` method: `value.Replace("px", string.Empty).Replace("em", string.Empty).Replace("%", string.Empty)`.

Comment: Useful comment...(Mine was not very serious comment - whil `50px` makes some sence by itself, `1em` and other relative measurements give no useful result without context)